# How to use hook_views_query_alter to add field with no table in Drupal 7 Views 3

Tags: views

I am new to Drupal 7/Views 3 hooks. I am trying to approximate this query:

```
SELECT *, 3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN(($postcode_lat - abs(lat))*pi()/180/2),2) + COS($postcode_lat * pi()/180) * COS(abs(lat) * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN(($postcode_lng - lng) * pi()/180/2),2))) AS distance 
WHERE distance < 500
ORDER BY distance ASC
```

This gives a list of locations sorted by distance. However, in trying to implement with hooks, I am struggling. Here is the code that I tried:

```
$query->addField('', '3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((32.7828 - abs(29.7631))*pi()/180/2),2) + COS(32.7828 * pi()/180) * COS(abs(29.7631) * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((96.8039 - 95.2665) * pi()/180/2),2)))', 'distance');
```

Drupal doesn't like the empty parameter for table. But how can I add a field with no table?

I appreciate any suggestions offered.

Comment: You can only use column aliases in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses, but not in WHERE clauses. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/942592/2016870

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. And I've solved it.

```
    function ModuleName_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->name == 'my_view' && 'my_block_name' == $view->current_display)) {


    $formula = "3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN(($postcode_lat - abs(lat))*pi()/180/2),2) + COS($postcode_lat * pi()/180) * COS(abs(lat) * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN(($postcode_lng - lng) * pi()/180/2),2)))";

    // Sets the formula's alias.
    $query->add_field(NULL, $formula, 'distance');
    $query->add_where(0, "$formula < 500", array(), 'formula');

    // Sets the order by reference
    $query->orderby = array(
      array(
        'field' => 'distance',
        'direction' => 'ASC',
      )
    );
  }
}
```

See http://roldanarts.com/2013/11/22/diego-f-roldan/blog/using-formulas-views-hook-views-query-alter for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`SelectQuery::addExpression()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3AaddExpression/7) method (instead of `addField()`) to add complex expressions to the query. e.g.

```
$formula = '3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((32.7828 - abs(29.7631))*pi()/180/2),2) + COS(32.7828 * pi()/180) * COS(abs(29.7631) * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((96.8039 - 95.2665) * pi()/180/2),2)))';
$query->addExpression($formula, 'distance');
$query->condition('distance', 500, '<')->orderBy('distance');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 

I tried that code that you supplied and received an error: An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
`code`
HTTP Result Code: 200
Debugging information follows.
Path: /admin/structure/views/view/membership_directory_2013/preview/default/ajax
StatusText: OK
ResponseText: 
Fatal error:  Call to undefined method views_plugin_query_default::addExpression() in /sites/all/modules/membership/membership.module on line 51
`code`

Regarding a views-compatible module with proximity capability, unfortunately I am using CiviCRM fields in the View, which does not support proximity.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add fields using `hook_views_query_alter()`.

You need to use [`hook_views_data()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7) or [`hook_views_pre_render()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7).

See [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/41010/11306) for [show fields after adding joins in hook_views_query_alter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41009/show-fields-after-adding-joins-in-hook-views-query-alter) for more info.

Comment: we should use hook_views_data() instead of hook_views_query_alter() or we should use them both as a complementary way? And how can we use EntityViewsData instead of hook_views_data() since I'm using drupal 8.