# Sorting Views by Day and Month only

Tags: 7, views, datetime

For a Birthday field using the [Date](https://www.drupal.org/project/date) module, [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) sorts it by year.  This puts the dates in basically random order once you format it to display only the month and the day.  Could it sort by day and month only?

**Extra bonus question**: Could Views sort the Birthdays in context of the current day so the upcoming Birthdays float to the top?

Comment: Kinda related to this: [Filter between first and last day of the current month in any year](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/175269/filter-between-first-and-last-day-of-the-current-month-in-any-year?noredirect=1#comment213650_175269)

Answer (score 0):

Never used this module, might be worth looking into. It has [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) integration.

### [Birthdays](https://www.drupal.org/project/birthdays)

> The Birthdays module allows users to add their birthday to their profile. It also lists birthdays on a seperate page and in different blocks. Users can receive an e-mail on their birthday automatically, and the administrator can receive periodic reminders of who are having their birthday. Uses Profile module from core.

Comment: My Birthday fields come from nodes.  It looks like that module works with users.  I'll give it a try tho.

Comment: (O_O) ....why would you put your b-day fields in nodes? :O

Comment: It's for long term clients.  Old persons home.